# Is that possible to put web code locally when building hybrid apps using native language?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs

My friends and I are building an app using native language on ios and android page. We want to use one or two pages using angular/ionic. I have wrote some ionic pages which are invoked by native languages through url. However, it's a bit slow when transfer the native page to ionic page using url. Therefore, I am wondering that is there any way to put web code locally with android code/ios code so native code can communicate with web code faster? I know ionic can build native crossing-platform app, but for now we just use it as supplement.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the open [source code of 2048](https://github.com/uberspot/2048-android) which has web code stored locally in the assets.